# How to save load data with pickle and the re use the anchor data in another script

Tags: python, pycharm, pickle, pyautogui

I have been coding a snapchat bot that automatically clicks on your screen using pyautogui. I use anchors to save the mouse points and I want to use pickle to save the anchor data to a file to use it again in another script that runs once a day. here is the code for the first one

```
import pyautogui as pag
import sys, json, requests, keyboard, time
import pickle

anchorNames = ["Camera Button", "Picture button", "Pick", "Group Button", "Select Button", "Send Button"]
anchors = []


anchorsFulfilled = 0
anchorsRequired  = len(anchorNames)

print(":: Click enter when your mouse is over '{0}' ::".format(anchorNames[anchorsFulfilled]))

while anchorsFulfilled != anchorsRequired:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "enter":

        mousePositionNow = pag.position()
        anchors.append(mousePositionNow)
        print("Successfully captured mouse coordinates.\n")
        anchorsFulfilled += 1
        if anchorsFulfilled == anchorsRequired: break
        print(":: Click enter when your mouse is over '{0}' ::".format(anchorNames[anchorsFulfilled]))
        time.sleep(1)

print("Cords captured: {0}\n".format(anchors))
print("Go Back To Picture Page And Press Enter to Start")



def sender():
    global anchors1
    cameraButton, pictureButton, pick, groupButton, selectbutton, sendButton = anchors

    pag.moveTo(pictureButton)
    pag.click(pictureButton)
    time.sleep(2)

    pag.moveTo(pick)
    pag.click(pick)
    time.sleep(1)

    pag.moveTo(groupButton)
    pag.click(groupButton)
    time.sleep(1)

    pag.moveTo(selectbutton)
    pag.click(selectbutton)
    time.sleep(1)

    pag.moveTo(sendButton)
    pag.click(sendButton)
    time.sleep(1)

    pag.moveTo(cameraButton)
    pag.click(cameraButton)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    with open("redo.txt", 'wb') as fp:
        pickle.dump(anchors, fp)


time.sleep(1)
if keyboard.read_key() == "enter":
    sender()
```

as you can see it saves to redo.txt file to use later.
but when I try to append the text file in the second script to the anchor data I get this error.

> cameraButton, pictureButton, pick, groupButton, selectbutton,
> sendButton = anchors ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected
> 6, got 1)

here is the code from the second script

```
import time
import pickle
import pyautogui as pag



anchors = []
pickle_in = open("redo.txt", "rb")
example_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)
with (open("redo.txt", "rb")) as openfile:
    while True:
        try:
            anchors.append(pickle.load(openfile))
        except EOFError:
            break

def redo():
    global anchors
    cameraButton, pictureButton, pick, groupButton, selectbutton, sendButton = anchors

    pag.moveTo(pictureButton)
    pag.click(pictureButton)
    time.sleep(2)

    pag.moveTo(pick)
    pag.click(pick)
    time.sleep(1)

    pag.moveTo(groupButton)
    pag.click(groupButton)
    time.sleep(1)

    pag.moveTo(selectbutton)
    pag.click(selectbutton)
    time.sleep(1)

    pag.moveTo(sendButton)
    pag.click(sendButton)
    time.sleep(1)




time.sleep(3)
redo()
```

How can I fix this error and import the anchor data to the anchors in the second script?

Comment: `anchors` is an array, is it Python might be pickling the array rather than the individual elements contained within it. This might explain why Python is saying it is only receiving one value rather than 6. Please try checking the datatype of the data read in from the pickled file using the [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Toothless204 mentioned in the comments, you are pickling the `anchors` list and loading it back into another list using `append`. So the variable `anchors` in your second script is a list containing your original `anchors` list. In other words, it is a list of lists. Try this out for yourself:

```
import pyautogui as pg
import pickle
import time 

anchors = []

pos1 = pg.position()
anchors.append(pos1)
print('Move mouse to a new location')
time.sleep(3)
pos2 = pg.position()
anchors.append(pos2)

with open('savefile.txt','wb') as fp:
     pickle.dump(anchors,fp)
 
print('anchors = ' , anchors)

anc1 = [] 
# append the anchors list to the list anc1, which results in a list of lists 
with open('savefile.txt','rb') as openfile:
    try:
      anc1.append(pickle.load(openfile))
    except:
      print('File read error')
print("anc1 = ", anc1)# anc1 is a list whose first and only element is the original anchors list
t1,t2 =anc1[0] # note that we use anc1[0] instead of anc1
print('t1 =', t1)
print('t2 =', t2)

# load the anchors list into anc2
with open('savefile.txt','rb') as openfile:
    try:
      anc2 = pickle.load(openfile)
    except:
      print('File read error')
print("anc2 = ", anc2)
t3,t4 = anc2
print('t3 = ',t3)
print('t4 =', t4)

anc3 = [] 
# extend list anc3 with the elements of the original anchors list
with open('savefile.txt','rb') as openfile:
    try:
      anc3.extend(pickle.load(openfile))
    except:
      print('File read error')
print("anc3 = ", anc3)
t5,t6 =anc3
print('t5 =', t5)
print('t6 =', t6)
```

Here is a sample output:

```
anchors =  [Point(x=510, y=741), Point(x=1571, y=210)]                                                                  
anc1 =  [[Point(x=510, y=741), Point(x=1571, y=210)]]                                                                   
t1 = Point(x=510, y=741)                                                                                                
t2 = Point(x=1571, y=210)                                                                                               
anc2 =  [Point(x=510, y=741), Point(x=1571, y=210)]                                                                     
t3 =  Point(x=510, y=741)                                                                                               
t4 = Point(x=1571, y=210)                                                                                               
anc3 =  [Point(x=510, y=741), Point(x=1571, y=210)]                                                                     
t5 = Point(x=510, y=741)                                                                                                
t6 = Point(x=1571, y=210)
```

Comment: Thanks I did it but I got this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @GaboniBones Do you see that error when you run the code I posted above or is it in your code? If it is the former, which line did you observe that at and is the output from your print statements similar to what I have until that line?

Comment: Ya I fixed it. thanks you so much for the help.